# Rails 4 - How to upload a file to s3 after form validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

In rails 4, I am using `s3_direct_upload` and `paperclip` gems for file uploads. Right now as soon as when I select or drag a file it will get upload to s3 directly.

Model code is,

```
attr_accessible :direct_upload_url

has_attached_file :document,
:url => '/cv_uploads/:recruiter_id/:unique_id/:resume_basename.:extension',
:path => "/cv_uploads/:recruiter_id/:unique_id/:resume_basename.:extension",
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3_credentials/public_s3_details.yml",
:s3_permissions => 'public-read'
```

Now I want to upload a file in a normal way along this feature, the file should get upload to s3 once form validation happens.
Here same model is using for both but normal file upload is not working, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Where is the form validation happening, in the browser using javascript, or in the backend once you submit values?

Comment: Validation is happening in the backend (model validation) after form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers you gave me above you have two options (the one that makes more sense depends on the other requirements you have in your project):

1) Split the form into two forms, the first one collects all parameters (but no files) and submits them to the server. If the parameters are fine, the user is brought to the second form where (s)he can upload the file to S3 and complete the form. 
Pros: you are uploading the file directly to S3
Cons: you are now having a two-stage form and you either need to store the form state either in a temporary DB object, in the session state or in the form itself using hidden fields

2) Stop using `s3_direct_upload` gem and instead upload the file to your server along the parameters. The server then validates the parameters and pushes the files to S3. 
Pros: the form remains stateless
Cons: you are having files going through your app server, which increases the need for bandwidth and temporary disk space.